# Removing unsupported unicode characters otherwise shown as squares

Tags: javascript, unicode, special-characters

I'm screwing around with some javascript that would insert a random miscellaneous unicode symbol somewhere in a document. ([like these symbols](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/miscellaneous_symbols.html))

However, I want to make sure that I'm only inserting the generated character, if that character is not to be printed as one of those "੟" squares.

So far, I'm generating random numbers between 2600 and 2699. But I want to make sure they're valid and not squares. Nevermind the fact that I'm not generating hex codes, just ints, it doesn't really matter which symbols I'm missing.

`String.fromCharCode(2600+(Math.floor(Math.random()*70)));`

Calling this a few times would give me: "ਖ਼੕ੁ੡਴਱ੜਯ੉"

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two fundamental things that might show as such squares (or a question mark in a lozenge, or something different entirely, e.g. the code point value in a square):

1. An illegal character that gets replaced by U+FFFD Replacement Character for display
2. A character that has no glyph in the selected font (or others that might get substituted).

For the first case you can try throwing out invalid code points (non-characters), but for the second you have little choice in the matter, as it all depends on the font, the browser, other installed fonts, the technology used to render text, etc.

Comment: I see. So when a font doesn't have the glyph of a certain charcode, the browser substitutes it for a ੡, but the underlying charcode remains the same? In other words, you can't detect if that ੡ was written in the document.

Comment: Yes. In your case I see a small box with `0A61` in it, which isn't even a character.

Answer (score 1):

Just because it's Sunday, I hacked a little JS that tests whether the codepoint, when drawn on a canvas, looks like the 0xFFFF char. It was just a question of comparing pixels. So if your font (in the sample code I am using whatever default system font is there) doesn't have the codepoint, then it is drawn (hopefully) just like 0xFFFF.

This could be improved, but as a Sunday hack, it is quite satisfying. You can check out  [the code](https://github.com/dda/doIhaveThisCodepoint) on GitHub.